# SVG - arc animation jumping steps

Tags: svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to make an svg animation for a path. The start result and the end result are fine, but for some reasons there are no intermediate positions (the animation just jumps from start to end after the duration.

This is the code I'm using:

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#96cb61;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-width:10px;}</style></defs><title>percentage-green</title>
 <path 
  id="p1"
  class="cls-1"
         d="
          M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20
         "
 />
 <animate xlink:href="#p1"
      attributeName="d"
      attributeType="XML"
      from="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20"
         to="M 50 57.32050807568877 A 20 20 0 0 0 40 20"
      dur="10s"
 />
    </svg>
```

Comment: It works in Chrome but does not work in Firefox. However, the animation has a hickup due to strange way arcs are defined in SVG.

Comment: I actually think that the flag is the problem (4th param). For example if I make an smaller arc (lower than 180 degrees) it works as expected. When I pass 180 the problem appears. However... don't know how to make a bigger arc without that flag unless I use 2 arcs (and I would prefere not to).

Comment: @Codo Yeah... I guess 1 day a guy woke up and said "hey... let's not use polar coordinates for arcs - so every1 will just compute their own" :|. Joke aside... I wonder if there are any performance benefits with this choice.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, despite the difficulties you want to do an arc animation.

**Arc formula**

```
<path d="M mx,my A rx,ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag, sweep-flag x,y" />
```

`Large-arc-flag` and `sweep-flag`  are integer-constant, which take only two values of "0" or "1" and do not lend themselves to smooth animation.

[image]

You can make a discrete transition animation from a large arc when `Large-arc-flag = 1` to a small arc`Large-arc-flag = 0`

On the example below the location of the small arc is indicated by a red dashed line.

The coordinates of the beginning and end of the small and large arcs coincide, only the value of the flag `Large-arc-flag from" 1 "to" 0 "

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
<style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#96cb61;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-width:4px;}
</style>
</defs>
<title>percentage-green</title>
<g transform="scale(2)">
<path id="p1"
    class="cls-1"
        d="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20"> 
<animate 
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
  repeatCount="5"
         begin="Layer_1.mouseover"      
    from="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20"
        to="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 0 0 40 20"
        dur="2s" >
  </animate>
</path> 
 <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="3" stroke="dodgerblue" fill="none" />
 <path  d="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 0 0 40 20" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red" fill="none" /> 
 </g>
</svg>
```

*Animation begins when you hover the cursor*

**The second example**

Is similar to yours - the parameter "d" of the patch will change smoothly, with the constant value of `large-arc-flag = 1` (large arc)

Animation begins when you hover the cursor

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 300 300">
<defs>
<style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#96cb61;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-width:4px;}
</style>
</defs>
<title>percentage-green</title>
<g transform="scale(2)">
<path id="p1"
    class="cls-1"
        d="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20"> 
<animate xlink:href="#p1"
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
  repeatCount="5"
      values="M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20;M 50 57 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20;M 20 40 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20"      
    begin="Layer_1.mouseover" 
        dur="3s"
    restart="whenNotActive"  >
  </animate>
</path> 
 <circle cx="40" cy="20" r="4" stroke="dodgerblue" fill="none" />
 <path  d="M 50 57 A 20 20 0 1 0 40 20" stroke-dasharray="3" stroke="red" fill="none" /> 
 </g>
</svg>
```